# How do I delete registered user from Realm Object server using Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm

I tried my best to get this answer from the internet but unable to.
I am trying to delete a user from ROS but unable to find any specified api for this. My realm-js version is `1.10.3`.

Does this feature exist if not is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is only possible to delete a user through the server's dashboard.